# css media queries not working correctly

Tags: css, joomla, media-queries

I have a div(languages module) which is placed on top of an image that is located on the header of the page. The div is has an "absolute" position so that it stays on top of the image.

The problem is that when the width of the window gets resized under 1499px the the browser is not loading the correct css as it uses the second media query(max-width:1500px)

Other above media queries are working fine!

```
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
    .mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 920px;padding-top: 160px;}
}

@media(max-width:1500px) {
    .mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 920px;padding-top: 160px;}
}

} @media(max-width:1499px) {
    .mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 700px;padding-top: 130px;}
}
```

[image]

I need help on writing these queries.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a example that we can look at?

Comment: actually no. I couldnt upload it on a live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was an extra bracket before the last media query !!

Sorry for this

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to min-width and see if that resolves your problem. Or if that doesn't solve it you will have to try something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) and (max-width: 2499px) {
    .mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 920px;padding-top: 160px;
}
```

Comment: You will have to see if something else in the CSS is conflicting - check the dev tools and see where the styles are coming from.  Press f12 and inspect the element in question.

Comment: there's nothing in conflict

Answer (score 0):

Delete the bracket marked in bold before last media query @media(max-width:1499px). There is an extra bracket

```
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
.mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 920px;padding-top: 160px;}
}

@media(max-width:1500px) {
.mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 920px;padding-top: 160px;}
}

**}** @media(max-width:1499px) {
.mydiv{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-left: 700px;padding-top: 130px;}
}
```